# Trying to form a desired format - map codons

Tags: pandas, csv, txt

From the input codon file,
looks like

```
TTT F
TTC F
TTY F
TTA L
TTG L
TTR L
TCT S
TCC S
TCA S
TCG S
TCR S
TCY S
TCM S
TCK S
```

I am trying to make a txt file that looks like below

```
'TTC':'F', 'TTY':'F', 'TTA':'L', .....
```

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import re

data = pd.read_fwf('codons')
df = {'TTT':data["TTT"], 'F':data["F"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df,columns=['TTT','F'])
df['codondict'] = df.TTT.str.cat(df.F, sep=":")
df['codondict'].to_csv("codondict.csv")

# csv to txt 
csv_file = 'codondict.csv'
txt_file = 'codondict.txt'

with open(txt_file, "w") as output_file:
    with open(csv_file, "r") as input_file:
      [output_file.write(" ".join(row)) for row in csv.reader(input_file)]
    output_file.close()
```

But neither the csv file to txt file outputs gave me that desired format. I am eventually trying to use that desired output as a map to translate other given sequences.

Can anyone help me to get the desired output format?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`df.to_csv` without filename gives you a string, which you can modify and write to your txt:

```
# you don't really need other processing
df = pd.read_fwf('codons')

# csv package for quoting
import csv

with open('codondict.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(df.to_csv(quotechar="'", index=False, sep=':',
                      quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, line_terminator=', '
                     )
            )
```

Comment: thank you. but i need it to be like 'TTC':'F', 'TTY':'F',.. so 'TTC':'F' is like a pair, but the output of the code suggested it 'TTC', 'F', 'TTY','F'...

Comment: updated with `sep=':'`.